# Why is JQuery ajax call ignoring PUT response JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, put

I have the following call:

```
var params={type:"PUT", dataType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8", url:"api/servletpat", data:JSON.stringify(dataObject)};
$.ajax(params)
    .done(function(data, status, jqXHR){
        successCallback(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, thrown){
        if (jqXHR.status == 200){
            successCallback(null);
        }
    });
```

Although the server does send a JSON response, ajax executed the .fail case with jqXHR.status = 200.  Which means the returned data is not accessible.  I cannot use "GET" because GET encodes the submitted object in the URL and this is not acceptable.
What do I need to do to be able to read the returned JSON object ?
Thanks...

Comment: I would have thought that POST would be the next logical after GET

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: should be a server side error

Comment: user2310289, I am following guidelines for the API where POST is reserved for adding new objects, PUT for updating existing objects and GET to retrieve objects and metadata.

Comment: Arun P Johny, Emilio Gort, No error server or client side. Server executed the PUT, and returned proper return object and a success HTTP status (200).  The only problem is that the JQuery' ajax call, reported this as a fail (still with success status).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying an invalid value for the `dataType` setting. This causes the `.fail` callback to get called (instead of the `.done` callback), even though the `jqXHR.status` is 200. The second parameter to the `.fail` callback function (the "textStatus" parameter) will be `"parsererror"`.

[jsfiddle demo that fails](http://jsfiddle.net/5hdFe/1/)

You should have:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
dataType: "json",
```

[jsfiddle demo that succeeds](http://jsfiddle.net/7xx38/)

With the `contentType` setting, you are specifying the content-type for the ajax request. When you set `dataType` to `"json"`, you are telling jQuery that the response will be JSON. That causes jQuery to automatically parse the response into an object (or array or null) before passing it as the `data` parameter to the `.done` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

status 200 means OK, not that the data is not accessible
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Answer (score 0):

> TYPE has to be either GET or POST

Comment: Is this a quote from somewhere?

Comment: @john Nope.not a quote